# No message found under code for locale 'en_US'

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm facing a problem while getting the key value pair from the properties file during spring validation.

**Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="messageResource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" >
        <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Validator**

```
public class ValidatorPlayer implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        Player player = (Player) obj;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "id","test.to");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name","test.to");
    }

}
```

**JSP Form**

```
<body>
    <form:form commandName="command">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Id</td>
                <td><form:input path="id"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="id"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/getForm.action")
    public ModelAndView getForm(){
        return new ModelAndView("formd","command",new Player());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getForm.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveAdndValidateForm(@ModelAttribute("command") Player player,BindingResult errors){
        new ValidatorPlayer().validate(player, errors);

        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("formd");
        }

        return new ModelAndView("formd","command",new Player());
    }
}
```

in the `messages.properties` file I have defined test.to="some value" and this file is in src folder.
in bindingResult error is comming but 500 error is appering on web page saying the above mention error.

Comment: If it isn't available your file i probably not found, make sure it is in the root of the classpath.

Comment: It worked after changing the id name "messageResource" to "messageSource". Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, missed that one. The `MessageSource` is one of the few beans that is looked up by its name.

Comment: Why is that? Till now t was thinking that id is just to differentiate two bean having the same class. like <bean id="id1" class="Class1"> and <bean id="id2" class="Class1">

Comment: That is how the [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) detects that bean, there are a couple (`localeResolver`, `themeResolver`, `messageSource` and `multipartResolver` are the most well known ones) which are detected by name.